# URI Online judge 1435 Square Matrix I (Presentation Error)

Tags: java

[image: Here the sample input and output of this code]

Write a program that read an integer number N (0 ≤ N ≤ 100) that correspond to the order of a Bidimentional array of integers, and build the Array according to the above example.

**Input**
 The input consists of several integers numbers, one per line, corresponding to orders from arrays to be built. The end of input is indicated by zero (0).

**Output**
 For each integer number of input, print the corresponding array according to the example. (the values ​​of the arrays must be formatted in a field of size 3 right justified and separated by a space. None space must be printed after the last character of each row of the array. A blank line must be printed after each array.

This is My Code. Here I get presentation error always. I know when space or line is not matching then get presentation error.But here i don't understand why give me presentation error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FirstClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        while((n =input.nextInt())!= 0){
        int newArray[][] = new int[n][n];
        int hn = n/2;
        if(n%2 == 1) {
            hn++;
        }
        int a = 0;
        int b = n-1;

        for (int l = 1; l <= hn; l++) { 
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            for (int j = a; j <= b; j++) {
                newArray[i][j] = l;
            }
        }
        a++;
        b--;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print("  "+newArray[i][j]);
                }else {
                    System.out.print("   "+newArray[i][j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Show your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your printing logic. Try the following code for printing. I have checked the code in the online judge, and its working!

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
         if(j == 0) System.out.printf("%3d",newArray[i][j]);
         else System.out.printf(" %3d",newArray[i][j]);
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem. If you don't understand anything let me know. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot brother...Now "accepted". I have understood this code.